# CertGetNameString throws heap corruption

Tags: unicode, wincrypt

CertGetNameString() throws heap corruption error randomly, using the function CertGetNameStringW() does the same

LPCWSTR pszName = (LPCWSTR)malloc(cbSize * sizeof(TCHAR));
if (CertGetNameString(
pCurrentCertContext,
dwType,
dwFlags,
nullptr,
pszName,
cbSize))
{}

Comment: Don't mix `LPCWSTR` and `TCHAR`.  You may not be compiling with the correct `UNICODE` and `_UNICODE` definitions, which makes `TCHAR` == `char` instead of `wchar_t` and your `malloc` half the expected size.  Use `LPCWSTR`, `WCHAR` and `CertGetNameStringW` consistently.

Answer (score 0):

The code which involves usage of CertGetNameString() cyrpt api requires the code be built using preprocessor directive UNICODE enabled.

Comment: Or use `CertGetNameStringW` and `WCHAR` explicitly along with `LPCWSTR`.